# Weaken the pattern matching conditions

Tags: batch-file

For my folders' names I have names like these

```
Fringe.S04
Fringe S01
From.Dusk.Till.Dawn_S01.ITA
Fear_The_Walking_Dead_S01
Fear_The.Walking_Dead_S01
Gossip Girl s2
Gossip.Girl_s2

Hawaii_Five_0_S05
Hawaii.Five_0.S01
Hawaii Five-0 S05
Cape_Wrath_Pack_2
Cape Wrath Pack 1
C Era Una Volta
C'Era Una Volta
C' Era Una Volta
```

I want that ignore these punctuation symbols between the names

```
.
_
'
```

because I want that pattern matching for folder names works like that

Hawaii_Five_0 = **Hawaii Five 0**
Hawaii.Five_0.S01 = **Hawaii Five 0**
Hawaii Five-0 S05 = **Hawaii Five 0**
Fear_The.Walking_Dead_S01 = **Fear The Walking Dead**
Fear_The Walking_Dead = **Fear The Walking Dead**
Fringe.S04 = **Fringe**
Fringe S01 = **Fringe**
...

My actual code that I use is this

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\27\SO_51539948.cmd
@Echo off
Pushd %1
For /d %%A in (*) do For /f "delims=" %%B in (
  'Dir /B "*%%~nxA*" 2^>Nul '
) do If "%%~nxA" NEQ "%%~nxB" Move "%%~fB" "%%~fA\" 2>&1>>Nul
Popd
```

Comment: Without unifying the seperators that won't work, the  overhead to automate things to perfection will exceed maual labour soon.

Comment: One way was to use `for /F` with the punctuation symbols as delimiters, like: `for /F "tokens=1-10 delims=._' " %%A in ('dir /B /A:D') do @echo/%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F %%G %%H %%I %%J` (given that there are no more than 10 words); this does not remove the `S##` suffix though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this method it is very simple to insert additional delimiters:

**EDIT**: Code modified to fulfill the *new* requirements given in a comment.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd %1

set "digits=0123456789"
for /F "delims=" %%l in ('dir /B /AD') do for /F "tokens=1-9 delims='-._ " %%a in ("%%l") do (
   set "out="
   set "end="
   for %%t in (%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i) do (
      if "!digits:%%t=!" neq "%digits%" set "end=1"
      set "t=%%t"
      for /F %%n in ("!t:~1,1!") do (
         if /I "!t:~0,1!" equ "S" if "!digits:%%n=!" neq "%digits%" set "end=1"
      )
      if not defined end set "out=!out! %%t"
   )
   if /I "!out!" equ " Hawaii Five" set "out= Hawaii Five 0"
   move "%%l" "!out:~1!"
)
```

In this new code the "Hawaii_Five_0" name is correctly managed as special case.

Comment: mm...I press on this batch but it vanish after immediately without move folders inside pre-existent folder, look https://i.imgur.com/IKbafD1.png
The equivalence condition I need not to rename and merge folder names, but to move them to an pre-existing folder name. Help me to understand what you propose instead.

Comment: In your question you didn't said that there are _pre-existing folders_. See my edit. Please, note that the _new_ code requires that you give a parameter to specify the working folder, in the same way as your original example code...

Comment: mm.. is possible to process also if I don't create pre-existing folders ? mm..very interesting..because if this is possible I prefer a script solution without pre-existing folders.

Comment: @SuperSonic It's up to you to decide which solution meets your requirements best, but here the series with trailing 0/1 disappear as a (sub)folder.

Comment: @LotPings: If you are talking about "Cape_Wrath_Pack_2" and "Cape Wrath Pack 1" goes to the same subfolder, then this is the programmed behavior (as **I** understood this request). To cancel this behavior, just remove the `if "!digits:%%t=!" neq "%digits%" set "end=1"` line. As a mater of fact, doing that also fix the special case of "Hawaii Five 0", so the last related `if` can also be removed...

Answer (score 1):

The following batch tries to unify the folder names,
but due to discrepancies in your examples it can't work perfect.

1. .ita extension as last element doesn't fit the scheme
2. `Hawaii Five 0` will be reduced to `Hawaii Five` on a 2nd run.

### **Edit:Slightly better results after renaming folders**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\27\SO_51672484.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Base=%~1"
if not defined Base set "Base=%~dp0"
Pushd "%Base%"
For /d %%A in (*) do Call :Unify %%~nxA
Popd

Goto :Eof
:Unify change all delims to space
set "Folder=%*"
Set "Unified=%Folder:.= %"
Set "Unified=%Unified:_= %"
Set "Unified=%Unified:-= %"
Set "Unified=%Unified:'= %"
Set "Unified=%Unified:  = %"
Set "Unified=%Unified:  = %"

:: check for trailing S##
For %%S in (%Unified%) Do Set "Last=%%S"
Set "Series="
Echo=%Last%|Findstr /ie " s*[0-9][0-9]*" 2>&1>Nul && Set "Series=1"
Echo Unified:%Unified%
Echo Folder :%Folder%
Echo Series :%Series%
if defined Series (
    call set "Unified=%%Unified: %Last%=%%"
) else (
    if not exist "%Base%\%Unified%" (
        Ren "%Base%\%Folder%" "%Base%\%Unified%"
        Goto :Eof
    )
)
if "%Folder%" Equ "%Unified%" goto :Eof
if not exist "%Base%\%Unified%" MD "%Base%\%Unified%\"
move "%Base%\%Folder%" "%Base%\%Unified%\"
```

Sample output:

```
> tree
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
Volumeseriennummer : 5566-7788
A:.
└───Videos
    ├───C Era Una Volta
    │   ├───C' Era Una Volta
    │   └───C'Era Una Volta
    ├───Cape Wrath Pack
    │   ├───Cape Wrath Pack 1
    │   └───Cape_Wrath_Pack_2
    ├───Fear The Walking Dead
    │   ├───Fear_The.Walking_Dead_S01
    │   └───Fear_The_Walking_Dead_S01
    ├───Fringe
    │   ├───Fringe S01
    │   └───Fringe.S04
    ├───From.Dusk.Till.Dawn_S01.ITA
    ├───Gossip Girl
    │   ├───Gossip Girl s2
    │   └───Gossip.Girl_s2
    └───Hawaii Five 0
        ├───Hawaii Five-0 S05
        ├───Hawaii.Five_0.S01
        └───Hawaii_Five_0_S05
```

Comment: Batch seems don't start. I press but folders is not moved, look why: https://i.imgur.com/0FtsXlY.png

Comment: The batch expects to get passed a base folder as argument 1 as your (my) sample ;-) I just changed it to use the batch parent folder in none is supplied.

Comment: mm..seems works very good LotPings ! But.. why `From.Dusk.Till.Dawn_S01.ITA` is not moved inside *From Dusk Till Dawn* folder ? Maybe because there are two different signs `.` and `_` ? Ah..maybe for **.ITA** ?

Comment: Because it doesn't match the scheme with the series at the end, if you rename to `From.Dusk.Till.Dawn.ITA_S01` it should work also.

Comment: Thank you also for your answer